# ./configure fails because of freetype

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile something but this is what happens.

```
checking for FREETYPE... yes
checking whether Freetype works... no
configure: error: Please install a working Freetype library.
```

It seems to be contradictory. Freetype was already installed. I just got the newest version and tried ./configure again but got the same results.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Open the configure file and check if it is checking for a particular version while checking Freetype package.

If it is, you may give this a try.

Change the version that it is checking in "configure" to your installed Freetype version. (If your installed version is newer most likely it should work.)